# Visual Studio 2008 Crash on Viewing Build MSTest Results when Solution is Open

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: Can you provide more context here?  It's impossible to diagnose with only this small amonut of information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521243/mtlm-client-crash-when-viewing-test-case-result-history

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/383492/visual-studio-2008-crashes-on-exit-with-ide-on-second-monitor-and-output-error-list-history-find-results-on-main-first-monitor

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/120065/crash-on-viewing-code-coverage-of-loaded-trx-file-after-viewing-test-run-details